# jquery selector does not return jquery object in $(document).ready function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have problems applying a jQuery Plugin to a selector, so I added a debugger command in my $(document).ready function.

When I call the selector while being in the ready function, it returns the following object

[image: in ready function]

When I continue code execution and execute the selctor again, I get a jQuery object:

[image: after ready function]

What goes wrong? The document loading should be completed in $(document).ready function, right?

Comment: can you provide code or jsfiddle for this...Thanks

Comment: What version of jquery and which browser are you executing it with?

Answer (score 1):

Most of times you apply a plugin to an element, it wraps the element with some extra DOM objects. That may cause that, depending on the selector you use, you don't find it after applying the plugin. Specially if the selector is like `$("#parentID > .yourObjectClass")`